# C++ Linking error (Boost thread)

Tags: c++, boost, cmake

I've got a problem with boost thread library. When I add this library to my projects it starts to fail while compilation. I tried to add into CXX_FLAGS *-lboost_system* and *-lboost_thread*

CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 2.8)

set(PROJECT Refregiration_Telemetry-Device)

PROJECT(${PROJECT} CXX)

SET(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS ${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} "-std=c++11")

set(SRC_ROOT_DIR ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/)
set(EXECUTABLE_OUTPUT_PATH ${SRC_ROOT_DIR}/bin)

set(SRC_DIR ${SRC_ROOT_DIR}/src)
set(INCLUDE_DIR ${SRC_ROOT_DIR}/include)
set(LIB_DIR ${SRC_ROOT_DIR}/lib)

INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(${SRC_DIR} ${LIB_DIR} ${INCLUDE_DIR})

set(SOURCES main.cpp scheduler.cpp)
set(INCLUDES scheduler.hpp)

set(SOURCES_LIST)

foreach (class ${INCLUDES})
    LIST (APPEND SOURCES_LIST ${INCLUDE_DIR}/${class})
endforeach ()

foreach (class ${SOURCES})
    LIST (APPEND SOURCES_LIST ${SRC_DIR}/${class})
endforeach ()

#Boost include start
find_package (Boost COMPONENTS date_time thread)
include_directories (${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS})
link_directories(${Boost_LIBRARY_DIR})
#set (ADDITIONAL_LIBS ${ADDITIONAL_LIBS} ${Boost_LIBRARIES})
#Boost include end

add_executable (${PROJECT} ${SOURCES_LIST})

target_link_libraries (${PROJECT} ${Boost_LIBRARIES})
#target_link_libraries (${PROJECT} ${ADDITIONAL_LIBS})
```

Make log:

```
[ 50%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/Refregiration_Telemetry-Device.dir/src/main.cpp.o
[100%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/Refregiration_Telemetry-Device.dir/src/scheduler.cpp.o
Linking CXX executable ../bin/Refregiration_Telemetry-Device
/usr/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/Refregiration_Telemetry-Device.dir/src/main.cpp.o: undefined reference to symbol '_ZN5boost6system15system_categoryEv'
//usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_system.so.1.54.0: error adding symbols: DSO missing from command line
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [../bin/Refregiration_Telemetry-Device] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Refregiration_Telemetry-Device.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Comment: Read the error message more closely, you can easily make out that it's missing `boost::system::system_category`, which can be found by linking with the `boost_system` library.

Comment: To piggyback on Joachim's answer, change you call to find_package to add 'system', e.g. find_package (Boost COMPONENTS date_time thread system).

Comment: Can you put an answer in the answer box provided and then accept it. This is preferable to editing the word "solved" into the question. The question remains in the "unanswered" queue until an answer is accepted.

Comment: "DSO missing from command line", google it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

libboost_system.so is the primary requirement of libboost_filesystem.so, so make sure add **-lboostsystem** to your command build or add `find_package(Boost 1.60.0 COMPONENTS filesystem system REQUIRED)` to CMakeLists file.

PS: I used **Boost 1.60.0** for example, you can use whatever version for the build. Also this command is for linux, for building in windows you need to build boost using visual studio developer command prompt.